# google recaptcha is not load in wordpress popup register form

Tags: wordpress, fancybox

i have using wordpress site fancybox popup plugin and i had created custom register form and put google recaptcha in popup register form but it not display.

**i am using [bws_google_captcha] this code in form.**

**iframe is not load for this captcha**

i check in inspect element but iframe for recaptcha is not loaded

i had put same code for recaptcha in another form.  but sometimes captcha display and sometimes not.

so anyone help me!